# Прежде(,) чем пуститься в путь

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые? (Точно думаю, что нет.)

> Прежде(,) чем пуститься в путь, прошлое перечеркнуть; прежде(,) чем мосты спалить, двери затворить, оглянись назад, постой. Вспомни, сколько нам с тобой выпало счастливых дней, ветреных путей и дождей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**«Прежде чем»: обособление оборота запятыми**](https://kakpishem.ru/punktuatsiya/prezhde-chem-obosoblenie-oborota-zapyatymi.html)

> По значению «прежде чем» – это союз временной, а по структуре –
> составной, то есть состоящий более чем из одного слова. Он связывает
> части сложного предложения – главную и придаточную – подчинительной
> связью.
> <...>
> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «прежде(,) чем»,
> выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может расчленяться
> (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом
> «чем»), но чаще целиком входит в придаточную часть (и не разделяется
> запятой).
> <...>
> Если «прежде чем» стоит в самом начале предложения, запятая ставится на границе придаточного и главного.

*Прежде чем пуститься в путь, вымой ноги дважды.*

---

> Прежде чем пуститься в путь –
> Прошлое перечеркнуть.
> Прежде чем мосты спалить –
> Двери затворить.
>
> Оглянись назад, постой!
> Вспомни, сколько нам с тобой
> Выпало счастливых дней,
> Ветреных путей и дождей.

Жуууткий текст вкупе с пунктуацией, имхо.

Comment: Там точно нужны тирешки?

Comment: Леопольдик, это авторское.